# Filter results by comparison of fields in elasticsearch and kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to build a kibana visualization which displays the count of documents where field A is not equal to another field B.

These should be first aggregated by a term so that i have some groups on X axis. Then, for all of these different terms, I would like to display count where field A is not equal to field B.

```
Example
{
   "fieldA":"HR",
   "fieldB":"HR",
   "AggregateOnThisField":"A"
},
{
   "fieldA":"HR",
   "fieldB":"Admin",
   "AggregateOnThisField":"A"
}
{
   "fieldA":"Admin",
   "fieldB":"HR",
   "AggregateOnThisField":"B"
}
{
   "fieldA":"Admin",
   "fieldB":"HR",
   "AggregateOnThisField":"B"
}
```

So, there will be two points on X axis representing A and B. A will have count 1 and B will have count 2. I know how to plot terms on X axis but finding hard to implement this filter.

running v7.2 of both.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding a Scripted Field to my index.
To do this, go to Management -> Index Patterns -> select your index -> Scripted fields

Since I needed a boolean output, selected the same as a drop down in Type.

Then in Script, added these lines,

```
if(doc['fieldA.keyword'].value.toLowerCase().equals(doc['fieldB.keyword'].value.toLowerCase()))
    {
         return true;
    }
    else
    {
         return false;
    }
```

fieldA and fieldB are strings so used .keyword

After addition of this script, I was able to use it as a field in kibana visualization.